# ffmpeg How to make timed picture overlay changes that repeat

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello I am working to figure out how to make it so that my live stream has logos that change into another logo every 20 seconds currently all I have been able to figure out is how to enable them at a certain time like this.

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8" -i ./public/images/ACE.png -i ./public/images/logo2.jpg -i ./public/images/crunchy.png -i ./public/images/red.jpg -filter_complex \
"[0]scale=1290:720,setsar=1[ovrl0]; \
 [1]scale=40:40[ovrl1]; \
 [2]scale=40:40[ovrl2]; \
 [3]scale=40:40[ovrl3]; \
 [4]scale=40:40[ovrl4]; \
 [ovrl0][ovrl1] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/1.025:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/18:enable='lt(mod(t,40),10)'[v1]; \
 [v1][ovrl2] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/1.025:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/18:enable='between(mod(t,40),10,20)'[v2]; \
 [v2][ovrl3] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/1.025:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/18:enable='gt(mod(t,40),20)'[v3]; \
 [v3][ovrl4] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/1.025:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/18:enable='gt(mod(t,40),30)'" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/2222-2222-2222-2222"
```

Comment: So you wish the watermark to alternate between the two PNGs in your command line?

Comment: Yes, I want figure out a way so that the logos alternate each other throughout the stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set enable for first logo overlay to `lt(mod(t,40),20)`, and for 2nd logo overlay to `gte(mod(t,40),20)`.

This will show 1st logo at `t = 0-20,40-60,80-100..` and 2nd logo at `t = 20-40,60-80,100-120..`

Comment: This worked! I hope you find a 20 dollars on the floor today!

Comment: Follow up question if you have the time, I am not quite understanding how gte works, say if I want to use a third logo and each rotates at 10 seconds, what would the code look like then?

Comment: First overlay  = `lt(mod(t,30),10)`; second overlay = `between(mod(t,30),10,20)`; third overlay = `gt(mod(t,30),20)` `gte` == `greater than or equal to`

Comment: hey I know you answered this question a long time ago but could you show me how would I go about changing the resolution of the video itself? I have been struggling for hours on this

Comment: Start filter_complex with `[0]scale=W:H,setsar=1[vid]` and then overlay inputs should be `[vid][ovrl1]`

Comment: I've changed the question code to be more readable. For some reason this is still outputting a very low quality image, I understand from hours of research that complex filtergraphs require re encoding a video but changing the resolution doesn't improve the image quality, what am I missing? I've tried rescaling like this, I've tried changing the bit rate I've tried qscale:v nothing seems to work

Comment: What's the original resolution of the video?

Comment: https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8 is 720p